# Create New Customer Account - Shop Required Error

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-account

I'm developing a new theme for Magento 2.1.3. When trying to create a new account, I'm getting an error saying `"Shop Type" is a required value.` Nothing in the logs sheds any light on this.

I'm overriding the default register template but the issue remains even when I'm not.

FYI, I am running a database that was migrated from 1.9

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete **Shop Type** attribute from **eav_attribute** table. It seems additional customer attribute and required field. So once you delete it, it will not show this error.

Comment: @chantron Welcome. I'm glad it helped.